# Restrict Consumers from publishing data in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

As the title suggest I am looking for a way to restrict the Kafka Consumers to publish the data to my kafka topic . For example we can have read only user in the database .

My use case requires me to get the data from some vendors, enrich this data and publish it to our Kafka topic. The data from this topic will be be read by few consumers. And as I understand I have to provide the same username and password ( the one that producer is using ) to the consumers.  So is there some way to stop consumers to publish the data in the Kafka topic .

E.g: restricting based on the username/ IP address.

Comment: "as I understand I have to provide the same username and password ( the one that producer is using ) to the consumers" - can you explain this assumption? Are you working with an existing Kafka environment with security configured?

Comment: we have an existing  Kafka environment and the user with which our producers publish to our Kafka is the same user with which our consumers connect to  our Kafka

Comment: So how is security configured on your current environment? Because by default you just produce/consume to Kafka,w/out authentication.

Comment: Consumers don't publish... That would imply they are both a producer and consumer

Comment: @RobinMoffatt we have security configured so we connect via user and password. And the consumers are also using the same user and password. I think I need to speak with infrastructure team to check if they can provide a read only ( subscribe only user) . Thanks for asking the right questions, gave me some direction.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no such feature in Kafka.

Apache Ranger and Open Policy Agent are example systems that you can implement much richer ACL policies than the Zookeeper options built-in. In my experience, only Ranger can do IP whitelisting.

I don't think the default Zookeeper ACL policies can do much other than username&password access.